# How to contain text box in parent div

Tags: html, css, overflow

In the [following HTML/CSS example](http://codepen.io/anilnamde/pen/CxDfG), the text box is extending beyond the borders of `div`. Though with input is `display:block` and has width of 100%, I expect the text box to stay in `div`.

Why it does not stay in the parent container? How can I fix it so that it becomes responsive and stays in the parent border?

```
<div class="first">
  <input type="text" value="not working" />
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<div class="sec">
  <input type="text" value="not working" />
</div>

<br/>
<div class="second">
  <span class="second-wrap">
    expected layout with text box
  </div>
</div>

div.first{
  width:50%;
  border:3px solid black;
}

div.first input{
  display:block;
  padding:20px;
  border:3px solid blue;
}

.sec{
  width:50%;
  border:3px solid black;
}

.sec input{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  padding:20px;
  border:3px solid blue;
}

div.second{
  border:3px solid red;
  width:50%;
}
.second-wrap{
  border:3px solid blue;
  display:block;
  padding:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the border and padding to the full width, if you do **not** set `box-sizing: border-box`.

Use these changes on input CSS

```
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
```

See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/vtael)

Comment: issues like these take me back to school every time ... :) thanks :)

Comment: @AnilNamde You may read about box model [here](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)

Answer (score 0):

For your input text you have assigned 100% width + 20px padding + 3px border. So that it is extending the parent div area.

You can use calc function to apply the width for the textbox properly. Update your css like below.

```
.sec input{
  display:block;
  width:calc(100% - 46px); /*20px left+20px right+3px border left+3px border right*/
  padding:20px;
  border:3px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Better use box-sizing value, because a) calc is not recommended, if not neccessary and b) implementations may vary, c) `box-sizing: border-box` is [supported well](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing) by browsers

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your codepen to this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/czHwG

```
.sec input{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  padding:20px;
  border:3px solid blue;
 + height:100%;
 + box-sizing:border-box; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property to match the box model you have in your mind:

```
.sec input{
  ...
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the input css

Answer (score 0):

```
div.first,
div.sec,
div.second{
    width:50%;
    border:3px solid #ddd;
    margin:2px auto;
    background-color:#fff;
}

 div.first input,
 div.sec input,
 div.second span{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0 none;
    color: #777777;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

   <body>
      <div class="first">
         <input type="text" value="not working" />
      </div>

  <div class="sec">
    <input type="text" value="not working" />
  </div>

  <div class="second">
    <span class="second-wrap">
         expected layout with text box
     </span>
  </div>
 </body>
```